# How can I implement dynamic styling for ion-list elements with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic-framework app that has a list of messages. There are 4 types of messages, and depending on the type the message should be displayed on the list with a particular color in the left border.

The question is, how do I indicate the CSS color depending on the type of message?

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ion-content class="ionc">
  <ion-list class="list">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="mensaje in mensajes" class="listitem" ng-click="abrirMensaje($index)" 
    on-hold="mostrarMenu(mensaje, $index)">
      <h2><b>{{ mensaje.hid }}</b></h2>
      <h3>{{ mensaje.alert }}</h3>
      <p class="cont">{{ mensaje.mens }}</p>
      <p class="fecha">{{ mensaje.fecha }}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The CSS looks like this if I fix every message to have the same color (red):

```
.buzon-page .item-complex .item-content, .listitem {
  border: 4px;
  border-left-style: solid !important;
  border-left-color: red !important;
}
```

How can I change CSS coloring dynamically with AngularJS?

**UPDATE**

After modifying the code with the help of the first answer the color borders appear but they do not move with the items, that should as they have an **ion-option-button** applied to them.

This is the new HTML:

```
<ion-content class="ionc">
<ion-list class="list">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="mensaje in mensajes" 
    ng-class="mensaje.tipo == 'Promocion' ? 'clasePromocion': 
              mensaje.tipo == 'Aprobado'  ? 'claseAprobado' : 
              mensaje.tipo == 'Alerta'    ? 'claseAlerta'   : 
              mensaje.tipo == 'ATM'       ? 'claseATM'      : 'default'" 
    ng-click="abrirMensaje($index)" 
    on-hold="mostrarMenu(mensaje, $index)"
    item="item"
    class="item-remove-animate">

    <h2><b>{{ mensaje.hid }}</b></h2>
    <h3>{{ mensaje.alert }}</h3>
    <p class="cont">{{ mensaje.mens }}</p>
    <p class="fecha">{{ mensaje.fecha }}</p>

    <ion-option-button class="button-positive" ng-click="mostrarMenuComp($index)">
      Compartir
    </ion-option-button>
    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="mostrarMenuElim($index)">
      Eliminar
    </ion-option-button>

  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And this is the new CSS:

```
.clasePromocion {
  border-left: solid 6px #0078ff !important; /* azul */
}

.claseAprobado {
  border-left: solid 6px #faaf40 !important; /* amarillo */
}

.claseAlerta {
  border-left: solid 6px #ee4036 !important; /* rojo */
}

.claseATM {
  border-left: solid 6px #00a551 !important; /* verde */  
}

.default {
  border-left: solid 6px white !important; /* blanco por defecto */
}
```

So, the issue now is how to make the color borders move with the list items? Here is a capture of the problem: http://i57.tinypic.com/2r71o5c.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 4 types of messages, you can leverage [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to craft something similar to the following, where you'll map a class to the particular message you are interested in. In this case, I have a made up property called `type`, with values of `A` `B` `C` `D` and an extra `E` for demo purposes. Of course, this is a simplistic example - but the foundation here can be easily absorbed into your project specifics

```
<span  
    ng-repeat="msg in messages" 
    ng-class="msg.type == 'A' ? 'classA' : 
              msg.type == 'B' ? 'classB' : 
              msg.type == 'C' ? 'classC' : 
              msg.type == 'D' ? 'classD' : 'default'">{{ msg.text }}</span>
```

---

```
$scope.messages = [
    { 'type': 'A', 'text': 'message' },
    { 'type': 'B', 'text': 'message' },
    { 'type': 'C', 'text': 'message' },
    { 'type': 'D', 'text': 'message' },
    { 'type': 'E', 'text': 'message' } // -- will be .default
];
```

---

```
.classA { border-color: dodgerblue; }

.classB { border-color: tomato; }

.classC { border-color: limegreen; }

.classD { border-color: orange; }

.default { border-color: purple; }
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/o7vz8ctk/)

---

For a more complete example that targets `ion-item` elements directly, the suggestion above just needs slight CSS modification. Since you expressed you wish to have the border move with the `ion-item`, apply the style rule to the child `<a>` tag. Here is a possible solution

```
.classA a { border-left: solid 4px dodgerblue !important; }

.classB a { border-left: solid 4px tomato !important; }

.classC a { border-left: solid 4px limegreen !important; }

.classD a { border-left: solid 4px orange !important; }

.default a { border-left: solid 4px purple !important; }
```

[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVZqRB) - working example with `<ion-item>` elements

[Image Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZWUD.png) - target `<a>` tags to "move" with entry

---

Upon further investigation, In certain emulation environments, an `<a>` tag does not get rendered as a child element of `<ion-item>`. However, the immediate child element *will* have a class of `.item-content`  e.g. `<div class="item-content">`. In this case, let's change our CSS to target this class instead of a specific child element.

```
.classA .item-content { border-left: solid 4px dodgerblue !important; }
```

Comment: It works except for one thing: half of the border is the desired color and the other half is dark gray (http://i60.tinypic.com/33wabmd.jpg). It looks like a bug in Ionic. I can half solve it by changing the CSS to only `.item-complex { border-left: solid 4px; }`, but then I also have an **ion-option-button** applied to every list item, and the color border doesn't move with the items and it should (http://i57.tinypic.com/2r71o5c.jpg). Maybe I should post another question with pictures.

Comment: I'd disagree with posting another question. You wanted a way to dynamically style your items with AngularJS. This is a decent way to do so. Now you're having some minor css issue-not terribly problematic. Can you post a plunker which reproduces the exact css issues you're having? @DavidPrieto

Comment: @DavidPrieto I updated answer to more specifically address this using ionic elements

Comment: @DavidPrieto I again updated the pen to have the border "move" with the element. You just need to target the child `<a>` tag. [See working pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVZqRB)

Comment: Targeting the child <a> tag doesn't work in Ionic, the border just disappears and I did it exactly like the pen. Probably a bug in Ionic. Should I update the question with my new code or ask another one?

Comment: @DavidPrieto You said you wanted the border to move, and the updated pen moves it with the swipe. Update question, but include a Plunker that reproduces the exact issue

Comment: Also what do you mean it doesn't work? It works fine in the pen. Can you clarify?

Comment: the boder disappears when adding the a in the CSS "classA a {.." it just shows the normal list without any color borders. I'm still trying to figure out how to make a Plunker.